# Subshifts with special property

Tags: dynamical-systems

I am looking how to prove the following fact:

If $ X \subseteq A^\mathbb{Z}$ is a minimal subshift, then $X$ is conjugate to a minimal subshift $Y\subseteq B^\mathbb{Z}$ such that for any $y\in Y$, $y(i)\neq y(j)$ if $|i-j|\le 4 , i\neq j$.

(I have encountered this in a paper in which the author asserts this without a proof.)

Comment: It might be good to cite the paper in question. (It seems the alphabet $A$ is extended to $B$ by adding admissible words to have no repetitions.)

Comment: The question was answered in Mathoverflow here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413250/subshifts-with-special-property/413258#413258